# Finding a bound for $\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{\sin B+\sin C}A$ if $\triangle ABC$ is not obtuse.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality, contest-math, triangles

The following question appeared in a JEE mock exam held two days ago.

**Question:**

$\triangle ABC$ is not obtuse then value of $\displaystyle\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{\sin B+\sin C}A$ must be greater than

- A) $\frac6\pi$
- B) $3$
- C) $\frac{12}\pi$
- D) $\frac1\pi$

**My Attempt:**

I first tried with sine rule $$\frac a{\sin A}=\frac b{\sin B}=\frac c{\sin C}$$

But couldn't do anything with it.

Then I used $\sin B+\sin C=2\sin\left(\frac{B+C}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{B-C}2\right)=2\cos\frac A2\cos\left(\frac{B-C}2\right)$

But couldn't finish this approach either.

Then I tried using Jensen inequality but in vain.

Then I thought I would assume a function and find its minimum value. But couldn't decide what function to take.

Comment: If a triangle is not obtuse, then $a^2+b^2\le c^2$ for all permutations of $(a,b,c)$. Try using this fact coupled with the law of sines.

Comment: @TheBestMagician that means $\sin^2C\ge\sin^2A+\sin^2B$?

Comment: I made a typo, $a^2+b^2\ge c^2$ haha. But yeah applying law of sines you get $\sin A=\frac{a}{2R}$, etc. so $\sin^2 A+\sin^2 B\ge \sin^2 C$.

Comment: @TheBestMagician oh yes. $$\cos C=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$$ Since cosine is non-negative. So, $a^2+b^2\ge c^2$. Is there any other way to prove this fact?

Comment: Fix $A$ and $B$. Consider the locus of points $C$ such that the triangle is obtuse. Do this by drawing the circle with diameter $AB$.

Comment: @TheBestMagician $$\sin^2 A\ge\sin^2C-\sin^2B\\\implies\sin^2A\ge\sin(C-B)\sin(C+B)\\\implies\sin^2A\ge\sin(C-B)\sin A\\\implies\sin A\ge\sin(C-B)$$Not sure what to do next

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure either. Try using AM-GM.

Comment: Note that if the value in question is always greater than any of the options, then it must be greater than the smallest one of them.  Therefore, the answer has to be D. </joke>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another answer, elementary this time. Make everything have as common denominator $ABC$. Then the sum is

$BC\dfrac{\sin B+\sin C}{ABC}$+$AC\dfrac{\sin C+\sin A}{ABC}$+$AB\dfrac{\sin A+\sin B}{ABC}$                   $(1)$

Now notice that the function $\,\,\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ is strictly decreasing on $[0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}]$. (Elementary calculus). Therefore

$\dfrac{\sin A}{A}\geq\dfrac{2}{\pi}$. Likewise for $B,C$. Then $(1)$ gives that the sum is

$\geq$

$\dfrac{B}{A}$$\dfrac{2}{\pi}$+$\dfrac{C}{A}.\dfrac{2}{\pi}$+......$\geq\,6\dfrac{2}{\pi}$=$\dfrac{12}{\pi}$.

(Because $\dfrac{A}{B}+\dfrac{B}{A}\,\geq\,2$ for any positive $A,B.$)

This does NOT provide a minimum but it gives one of the answers (and therefore all the others are correct)!!

Answer (score 3):

For an exam, I would try first a trivial case, $A=B=C=\frac\pi 3$. Then $\sin A=\frac{\sqrt 3}2$, so $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sin B+\sin C}{A}=3\frac{2\sin A}{A}=\frac{9\sqrt 3}\pi$$
The largest value from your choices is $\frac{12}{\pi}$, which is smaller than the value above. So the answer is C

Comment: Thank you  .....

Answer (score 3):

A previous answer is correct, but is not a proof! There are many ways to get a minimum! The simplest is to set $A=x, B=y, \,\,C=\pi-x-y$ and try to minimize the function

$f(x,y)=\dfrac{siny+sin(\pi-x-y)}{x}+\dfrac{sin(\pi-x-y)+sinx}{y}+\dfrac{sinx+siny}{\pi-x-y}$.

Taking partial derivatives we get:

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$= $-\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}(siny+sin(x+y))+\dfrac{1}{x}cos(x+y)+\dfrac{1}{y}(cos(x+y)+cosx)+\dfrac{cosx(\pi-x-y)+sinx+siny}{(\pi-x-y)^{2}}=0$

and likewise for $\,\,\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. Now it is time to use our intuition and see that $x=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ and $y=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ are solutions of the system and hence a stationary point.
Therefore the value of $f$ at this point is $\,\dfrac{9\sqrt{3}}{\pi}$
and to make sure it is not a maximum we use $A=\dfrac{\pi}{2}, B=\dfrac{\pi}{4}, C=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ which gives $\dfrac{8+6\sqrt{2}}{\pi}$ a greater value than $\dfrac{9\sqrt{3}}{\pi}$. Therefore, the minimum value of the function is $\,\,\dfrac{9\sqrt{3}}{\pi}$ and hence all answers are correct. If we have to decide which value is closer to the minimum, then it is $\dfrac{12}{\pi}.$

Comment: Thanks. Any chance we could give a proof without partial derivatives? Because that's not in syllabus.